# SQL*Loader is not working in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-loader

Hi I am working with SQL*Loader but its give me an error

> SQL*Loader-128: unable to begin a session
>
> ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol.

My Oracle is 12c and SQL*Loader version is 9.2.
[image]
What i have to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd give serious consideration to upgrading to a more recent version of SQL*Loader.

(Oracle 9 went out of support over 6 years ago)

Comment: Do I need to install instant client or install oracle setup?

Comment: Pretty sure that SQL*Loader needs Oracle Client (not just instant client).  But I suggest you check.

Comment: Yes, SQL\*Loader is part of the (full) Oracle Client. Presumably this error affects all of your Oracle client tools including SQL*Plus? Did you google "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol"? A lot of the results point to an Oracle client config issue.